# Modify an object before marshaling it in Ruby

Tags: ruby, serialization, marshalling, dump, superclass

I have an object containing sensitive data that I want to marshal (using `Marshal`) *without* the sensitive data.

I'd like to be able to say:

```
def _dump(*args)
  # Clean-up sensitive data
  super
end
```

but this produces a 'no superclass method' error. Is there a way I can make my object behave the way I want in response to `Marshal.dump`, while using the default implementation?

I want `Marshal.dump(my_obj)` to work out-of-the-box without requiring the API consumer to remember to call a different method.

Comment: Can you use `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be that there is no superclass method for `_dump`. If it's defined on your object it's called. If not, the default handler is used.

You probably want to `clone` your object and remove the sensitive fields, returning that as a Hash inside your `_dump` function, then undo that within the `_load` method.

You can also read [the documentation on Marshal](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Marshal.html) where it describes the recommended methods.